# How to get the selected value in a dropdownlist and post with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got a dropdownlist from which I want to post the value to a php script using ajax. I console log the value but what I get is this:

```
function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return d=m.isFunction(a),this.each(function(c){var e;1===this.nodeType&&(e=d?a.call(this,c,m(this).val()):a,null==e?e="":"number"==typeof e?e+="":…
```

This is my html/php select list:

```
<select class="aanbselect" id="aanbieding">
    <?
    // Haal alle diensten op en stop ze in een dropdownlist
    $aanblijst                      = "SELECT *
                                                         FROM snm_content
                                                         WHERE catid = 11 AND state = 1 ORDER BY ordering";
    $aanblijstcon               = $conn->query($aanblijst);
    $aanblijstcr                  = array();
    while ($aanblijstcr[]   = $aanblijstcon->fetch_array());
    foreach($aanblijstcr as $aanblijstje){
        if($aanblijstje['id'] != ''){
            $lijstoverzicht .= '<option value='.$aanblijstje['alias'].'>'.$aanblijstje['title'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo $lijstoverzicht;
    ?>
</select>
```

My ajax:

```
/* Ajax code voor aanbiedingen */
$("#aanbieding").on('change', function() {
    var option = $('#aanbieding > option').filter(':selected');

console.log(option.val);
    $.post("includes/getaanbieding.php" + option.data, {
        filter: option.val()
    }, function(result){
        $("#aanbiedingviewajax").html(result);
    });

});
```

How can I post the value of an option inside a select tag to getaanbieding.php?

Comment: You should call the `val` function (using `()`): `console.log(option.val())`

Comment: Thanks that worked :)

Comment: no, you should real about [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) in jquery's website.